# Adding a force based on mouse position

Tags: java, math

I want a point to move towards the mouse position. Currently the point just **is** the mouse location. But I want it so that the bigger the distance between mouse and center of the screen, the less force get´s added to the point. So if the mouse is enough distance away from the center, the point will just stop moving further outwards because it´s force away from the center is to small. The center should always be the point which is looked at. So no repositioning.

I am really stuck here because I am pretty young and I didn´t have had vector calculation in school (I think this is what you need here). I have no idea how to do what I am trying to archive. The only thing I tried was using the distance between center and mouse (`Math.hypot(width / 2 - mouseX , height / 2 - mouseY)`). But it didn´t work.

This is my [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Example extends JPanel {
    private static final int size = 500;

public Example() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size, size));
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2d.fillOval(getWidth() / 2 - 3, getHeight() / 2 - 3, 6, 6); // center
    Point point = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(point, this);
    // Do calculations with the point here
    g2d.fillOval(point.x - 5, point.y - 5, 10, 10);
    repaint();
}

private static void createFrame() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(new Example());
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(Example::createFrame);
    }
}
```

It would look like this:

[image: grafik.png]

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an attraction ratio value, which will strech the circle to the center of the screen, based on its value.
You need also be able to know for each cursor position how far it is from the center in percentages.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Example extends JPanel {
    private static final int SIZE = 500;
    private static final int CENTER_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 3;
    private static final int CIRCLE_RADIUS = 5;
    private static final double ATTRACTION_RATIO = 0.75;

    public Example() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        final int xCenterPoint = getWidth() / 2;
        final int yCenterPoint = getHeight() / 2;

        g2d.fillOval(xCenterPoint - CENTER_CIRCLE_RADIUS, yCenterPoint - CENTER_CIRCLE_RADIUS,
                CENTER_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2, CENTER_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2); // center
        Point point = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(point, this);

        final double xNearToCenter = 1 - ((double) (xCenterPoint - point.x) / xCenterPoint);
        final double yNearToCenter = 1 - ((double) (yCenterPoint - point.y) / yCenterPoint);

        g2d.fillOval((int) (xCenterPoint * (ATTRACTION_RATIO + xNearToCenter * (1 - ATTRACTION_RATIO))),
                (int) (yCenterPoint * (ATTRACTION_RATIO + yNearToCenter * (1 - ATTRACTION_RATIO))),
                CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2, CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2);

        repaint();
    }

    private static void createFrame() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Example panel = new Example();
        f.add(panel);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(Example::createFrame);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain in words how the code solves the problem. Add comments to lines or paragraphs with the explanation. This will help the OP and future readers better understand the approach you take.

Comment: Mh. Technically it is working because you can´t move the mouse over your screens edge -> The force goes to zero. But in my real code "the cursor" can move to infinity. Therefore the force never get´s smaller. How can I make it that the force get´s smaller the higher the distance from center to cursor?

Comment: @Lansik, you can decrease the ATTRACTION_RATIO, which is the ratio of the "almost not moving" distance from the edges. For example to 0.55

Comment: I am pretty sure it would look like that: https://i.ibb.co/DLkMN1w/Stack-Over-Flow-example-image.png

Comment: @Lasnik, absolutly not a straight horizontal line function. Try it in a finite space, and see that when you move the cursor outside the center point it become harder to "stretch the spring". That is because for each point the xNearToCenter and yNearToCenter values are different, and the result of that is the calculated point position is not a linear function.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code somewhat to create the following GUI.

[image: Mouse Move Example]

The circle will follow your mouse around the drawing `JPanel`.

The first thing I did was create a `Circle` class.  This class holds the center point, radius, and color of the circle.  I use a `Point2D` class to hold the center point so I can move the circle in fractional pixel increments.  This makes the animation smoother.

Next, I used your code to create a `JFrame` and a drawing `JPanel`.  I like to separate the `JFrame` code from the `JPanel` code.  It makes it easier for me to focus on one Swing component at a time.

The drawing `JPanel` draws the circle.  Period.  The controller classes are responsible for calculating the new position of the circle and calling the repaint method of the drawing `JPanel`.

I created a `MouseMotionListener` to listen for the mouse movement.  This class keeps track of the mouse position.

I created a Swing `Timer` to animate the motion of the circle.

I used polar geometry to calculate the direction that the circle moves.  The polar geometry is in the `MoveListener` class, the `actionPerformed` method. I use an arc-tangent to calculate the angle to the mouse position in radians, then take the cosine to get the X movement, and the sine to get the Y movement.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MouseMoveExample implements Runnable {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new MouseMoveExample());
    }

    private final int size = 500;
    
    private Circle circle;
    
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    public MouseMoveExample() {
        this.circle = new Circle(new Point(size / 2, size / 2), 12, 
                Color.BLACK);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Mouse Move Example");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
        f.add(drawingPanel);
        
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size, size));
            this.addMouseMotionListener(new MoveListener());
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(circle.getColor());
            Point centerPoint = circle.getCenterPoint();
            int radius = circle.getRadius();
            int diameter = radius + radius;
            g2d.fillOval(centerPoint.x - radius, centerPoint.y -  radius, 
                    diameter, diameter); 
        }
        
    }
    
    public class MoveListener extends MouseAdapter {
        
        private MoveTimer moveTimer;
        
        private Timer timer;
        
        public MoveListener() {
            this.moveTimer = new MoveTimer();
            this.timer = new Timer(20, moveTimer);
            this.timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
            moveTimer.setEventPoint(event.getPoint());
        }
        
    }
    
    public class MoveTimer implements ActionListener {
        
        private Point eventPoint;

        public void setEventPoint(Point eventPoint) {
            this.eventPoint = eventPoint;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            Point centerPoint = circle.getCenterPoint();
            if (eventPoint != null) {
                double theta = Math.atan2(eventPoint.y - centerPoint.y, 
                        eventPoint.x - centerPoint.x);
                int increment = 1;
                double x = Math.cos(theta) * increment;
                double y = Math.sin(theta) * increment;
                circle.incrementCenterPoint(x, y);
                drawingPanel.repaint();
            }
        }   
        
    }
    
    public class Circle {
        
        private final int radius;
        
        private final Color color;
        
        private Point2D centerPoint;

        public Circle(Point centerPoint, int radius, Color color) {
            setCenterPoint(centerPoint);
            this.radius = radius;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public Point getCenterPoint() {
            return new Point((int) Math.round(centerPoint.getX()), 
                    (int) Math.round(centerPoint.getY()));
        }

        public void setCenterPoint(Point centerPoint) {
            this.centerPoint = new Point2D.Double(
                    centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y);
        }
        
        public void incrementCenterPoint(double x, double y) {
            centerPoint.setLocation(centerPoint.getX() + x, 
                    centerPoint.getY() + y);
        }

        public int getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I tested the program. It is really nice. But it isn´t really what I was looking for. Your circle moves in linear speed but I would want to have a circle which increments based on the distance to the mouse. The bigger the distance between mouse and circle -> the slower the circle moves to the mouse. I propably formulatd my question wrong.

Comment: @Lasnik: The increment in the actionPerformed is a constant 1.  Calculate an increment between 0 and 1 depending on the distance to the mouse point.  I'm still not sure if you want to circle to speed up or slow down as it approaches the mouse point.  I'm also not sure if the speed of the circle is relative to the drawing JPanel center point or not.;

Comment: I think you completely missunderstood. Basically I want Roie Schlosbergs code but tweaked to this: https://i.ibb.co/DLkMN1w/Stack-Over-Flow-example-image.png
The point should be between center and cursor. Not freely movable